# reshape dataframe: columns to lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe df_given [n, m] and I want to change the columns values into line values at each 3 rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': np.arange(1,4), 'B1': np.arange(10, 13), 'C1': np.arange(20, 23)})
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': np.arange(11,14), 'B1': np.arange(100, 103), 'C1': np.arange(200, 203)})  
df_given = pd.concat((df_test1, df_test2), axis =0)

df_desired = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,10,20,11, 100, 200], 'B':[2,11, 21,12, 101, 201], 'C':[3,12,22,13, 102, 202]})
df_desired.head(10)

df_given.head(10)
```

Comment: Please paste the input and output in code format not images.

Comment: I posted the whole code from the beginning. Should I delete the pictures?

Comment: Code is fine, just replace your images with proper format.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what exactly do you mean. I will have to check the FAQ questions as I don't know what a proper format for images is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.concat` with `GroupBy`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

res = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(df_slice.T.values, columns=df.columns.str[0]) \
                for _, df_slice in df.groupby(df.index // 3)), ignore_index=True)

print(res)

     A    B    C
0    1    2    3
1   10   11   12
2   20   21   22
3   11   12   13
4  100  101  102
5  200  201  202
```

**Explanation**

- `df.reset_index(drop=True)` resets the dataframe index to the regular [`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.RangeIndex.html), i.e. `0, 1, 2, ..., n`.
- `df.groupby(df.index // 3)` groups the dataframe in chunks of 3 rows. We iterate over this `GroupBy` object in a generator comprehension.
- `df_slice.T.values` transposes the 3 rows which constitute a slice and converts to a NumPy array. We feed this to `pd.DataFrame` to construct a dataframe from a NumPy array.
- `pd.concat` takes an iterable of dataframes and combines them to construct a single dataframe.

Comment: Seems like there is no better way :-(

Comment: @Silvia, Sure, added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
pd.concat([x for _,x in df_given.groupby((df_given.index==0).cumsum())],axis=1).T
Out[997]: 
      0    1    2
A1    1    2    3
B1   10   11   12
C1   20   21   22
A1   11   12   13
B1  100  101  102
C1  200  201  202
```

Comment: I am pandas 0.23.0, and unfortunatelly this didn't work for me. The df is transposed, but I am getting still a (3,5) sdf shape

Comment: @Silvia it is work , you just forget assign it back df=pd.concat([x for _,x in df_given.groupby((df_given.index==0).cumsum())],axis=1).T

Comment: You are very right. My mistake. I am sorry, I have accepted the other  answer already, I just could gave you a +.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative using `groupby`, `stack` & `unstack`

```
df1 = df_given.assign(g=df_given.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).set_index('g',append=True)

df1 = df1.stack().unstack(0).reset_index(drop=True)

df1.columns = df_given.columns

print (df1)


   A1   B1  C1
0   1   2   3
1   10  11  12
2   20  21  22
3   11  12  13
4   100 101 102
5   200 201 202
```